# Proof of Artin's reciprocity law

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Where can I find a proof of Artin's reciprocity law that is accessible to someone who has taken a course on Algebraic Number Theory?

Comment: Cassels and Fro\"ohlich is a book with each chapter written by different authors.

Comment: Have a look at  Artin's original proof.

Comment: Perhaps https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/the-artin-reciprocity-law/ ?

Comment: @PVanchinathan Where is the proof that the Artin homomorphism is onto?  I know it should be in $\S$VII, but I can't find it...

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Keep in mind that, it is written in a different (mathematical) language than is used today; so the notations will all be weird, and it won't be the most straightforward proof available today.